# Communicate Multiple Emulators

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to make an http server on one android application and get its contents from another emulator.

Also other than http protocol, is there any other networking API + sample code that someone give me to connect and get content from one emulator to another?

Comment: I could never figure out how to communicate emulator -> emulator

Answer (score 0):

Emulator is behind a virtual router. To make it accessible to the outside world (including other emulators) you need to configure [Network Redirections](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections) (basically port forwarding)